# MS access form combo box row source based on current field value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Newb in Access (version I used: 2010) and VB. :(

I have a form and a table both named "issues", a combo box named "statusfield" (value list: open, reopen, wip, closed).

The form loads the content of table "issues" per record. One can modify the field value of records.

The aim is to show the available value list based on the current status of an issue.

For example, if the current value of "statusfield" is empty, when one clicks the combo box, available status would be "open;reopen;wip", and if the current value of "statusfield" is "open", then available status would be "wip;closed".

Could one explain as detailed as possible please? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I redesigned the database, created the one to many mapping in (Database tools -> Relationship), with the same vba, everything works as designed. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in the AfterUpdate event of the combobox

```
If Me.statusfield.value = "open" Then
   Me.statusfield.RowSource = "wip ; closed"
End If
```

Comment: Emi, I've tried the code (with RowSourceType="Field List") in Form_Current, AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate, Click, but it doesn't work. It shows empty on the selection list.

Comment: The RowSourceType property should be set as "Value List" where you will have to input the list of items with semicolons (;) as separators. "Field List" is  for a table name, query name, or SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks Emi, this is basically what I want except that I use it in the Form_Current event. Also, I changed the "Inherit Value list" (after two days of troubleshooting) to No. Everything works now! :)